# How can i get the context from the main activity and put it in the other activity inside the GridLayoutManager context?

Tags: java, android-studio

In my second activity I want to replace the "this" into the context of the main activity so that the recycleview will appear in the main activity, but I don't know how and what to do.

This code is from the second activity which is separated for the main activity:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
```

I need to get the context of the MainActivity.java to display the items to it.

Comment: There is no sense in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your in fragment call `getContext()` or `getActivity()` where `this` is required if your in adapter class just pass Context in cinstructor of the adapter class example `
public class BuyerProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BuyerProductAdapter.BuyerProductViewHolder> {

```
List<GetProduct.Response> responseList = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;

public BuyerProductAdapter(List<GetProduct.Response> responseList, Context context) {
    this.responseList = responseList;
    this.context = context;
}
```

}
now you can use context where `this` or `Context` is required.